# How to know when video conversion is completed?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I have successfully uploaded a video to Vimeo using the API, but after that It will take some time for video conversion..

Is there a way to check if video conversion has completed using the API?
I am looking for something like a callback URL..

Answer (score 1):

Currently the API does not perform a callback or push notification when an upload has completed video transcoding. Instead, you'll need to periodically make requests to the API to get the video's status.

To get a video's status, make a [filtered](http://developer.vimeo.com/api/common-formats#json-filter) request with these fields specified:

```
GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos/[video_id]?fields=uri,upload.status,transcode.status
```

The `upload.status` and `transcode.status` fields will return one of the following values:

```
complete
error
in_progress
```

Comment: A related question: Will vimeo banned me, If I hit the API rate limits? or it will just send back an error: "API RATE LIMIT HAS BEEN REACHED" kind of message?. If it was the second one .. then I don't need to keep recording vimeo API rate limits in my application to make sure I don't hit that limit..

Comment: @rook99 If your app/user exceeds rate limit, Vimeo will return a 429 error for the remainder of the 60-second polling period. More info here: https://developer.vimeo.com/guidelines/rate-limiting#exceed-quota

Comment: Thank you. Does Vimeo have a roadmap I can check? to see if they ever will implement such a feature ( callback or push notification when an upload has completed video transcoding)?