# Is there any callback option for being notifieid if the video uploaded successfully?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm uploading videos to vimeo using tus, when video is uploaded it's not ready to embed and displayed, so is there any callback mechanism that vimeo provide to know when the video is reday to embed and displayed ?

Answer (score 2):

- As per the Vimeo's [official developer
  documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos),

> If the value of Upload-Offset is the same as the size of the video
>   file, we received the entire file. Consider this video uploaded.

This is how you check if the file is completely uploaded or not. You can also verify it by comparing `Upload-Length` and `Upload-Offset` and if the values are same, entire file has been uploaded.

- Also, as found on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51676904/8244632), no callback mechanism is present but you can get status of the video being uploaded and transcoded by making a filtered request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but after vimeo receives the whole file they make some processing on the video before it's ready to be viewed on the website or embedded player, I need to know when these processes are finished, do you get what I mean ?

Comment: @user525442 The StackOverflow link I've provided is for the after-uploaded stuff.